# Find elements with overlapping classes using getByXPath

Tags: java, html, xml, dom, htmlunit

On my browser I have elements that share same classes with each other like

```
<span class="a8Pemb OFFNJ Jz5Gae">...</span>
```

and

```
<span class="a8Pemb OFFNJ">...</span>
```

However when I used `page.getByXPath("//span[@class='a8Pemb OFFNJ']");` it only returns me the second elements with exact same class names. I want to get all of them IN ORDER, which means I don't want to call a separate query for the first elements. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the XPath expression `//span[@class='a8Pemb OFFNJ']` is only going to return `span` elements whose `class` attribute is literally exactly equal to the string `'a8Pemb OFFNJ'`, and the string value `'a8Pemb OFFNJ Jz5Gae'` is not equal.

I believe you are limited to XPath version 1 in HTMLUnit, so you're not easily able to tokenize the `class` attributes into a list of separate tokens that you can compare. You could generate a more complex XPath expression that uses the XPath `contains()` function to check that the `class` attribute contains each of the classes you want, but probably it's easier and more robust to retrieve the `span` elements by CSS selector instead, using the `querySelectorAll` method and a CSS selector like `span.a8Pemb.OFFNJ`

Comment: The expression `//span[contains(@class, 'a8Pemb OFFNJ')]` would work for the specific example you gave, but it would also pick up `<span class="XXXa8Pemb OFFNJXXX">` and it would miss `<span class="OFFNJ a8Pemb">`. That's why it's more robust to use CSS which understands that `class` attributes contain a set of independent tokens, not just a string.